# XLdeploy: Not able to create a folder with correct name

Tags: xl-deploy, deployit

I have to create a folder inside a dar. I am using below code in my POM

```
<deployable>
                            <name>Test_APP_resource</name>

                            <scanPlaceholders>true</scanPlaceholders>
                            <targetPath>C:\jboss\bin\resource</targetPath>
                            <type>file.Folder</type>
                            <targetPathShared>true</targetPathShared>
                            <createTargetPath>true</createTargetPath>
                            <targetPathSharedSubDirectories>true</targetPathSharedSubDirectories>
                            <location>C:\jboss\bin\resource</location>

</deployable>
```

but when dar is creating I see only  resource folder not Test_APP_resource.

Using below Deployit version

```
                <groupId>com.xebialabs.deployit</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deployit-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.4</version>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `location` is probably not pointing to an actual folder. Also your `maven-deployit-plugin` version is certainly not supported anymore. You might want to upgrade to the `xldeploy-maven-plugin` version [6.0.x](https://docs.xebialabs.com/xldeploy-maven-plugin/6.0.x/index.html)

Comment: it is pointing to the correct folder. Till last Friday everything is working fine.